# Chart name doesn't appear after adding new series

Tags: vba, excel

I want to plot a bar chart with a line over it. When I plot only the bar chart, the name appears, but when I add another series, it disappears, and by adding ActiveChart.Name = "Name" does not work, neither ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Name" (which changes the name of the sheet). Thank you

```
 Dim myChtObj As ChartObject

Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
    (Left:=100, Width:=800, Top:=75, Height:=400)
myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
myChtObj.Activate

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = sheetName
    .Values = yValues
    .xValues = xValues
End With


ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Name = "line"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("line").Values = yValues
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("line").xValues = xValues
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("line").ChartType = xlLine


ActiveChart.legend.Select
Selection.Delete
```

Comment: Do you mean the series names disappears or the chart name?

Comment: You are essentially plotting the same series twice but when you assign the second time a name you wipe the first name.

Comment: Chart name disappears

Answer (score 0):

See the following to add a chart title to your chart and add a second series reference to ensure you have series added distinguished by number. I have added some dummy values. Works with just `SeriesCollection` or `FullSeriesCollection`.

You can use the macro recorder to record adding other elements.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim sheetName As String
Dim yValues As Range
Dim XValues As Range

sheetName = "aName"
Set yValues = Range("A2:A4")
Set XValues = Range("B2:B4")

Dim myChtObj As ChartObject

Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
    (Left:=100, Width:=800, Top:=75, Height:=400)

myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
myChtObj.Activate
myChtObj.Name = "myChartName"

With myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = sheetName
    .Values = yValues
    .XValues = XValues
End With

myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

With myChtObj.Chart
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""line"""
    .SeriesCollection("line").XValues = XValues
    .SeriesCollection("line").Values = yValues
    .SeriesCollection("line").ChartType = xlLine
    .Legend.Delete
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "My title" & Chr(13) & ""
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, will check in short time!

Comment: No worries. Please consider upvoting or accepting as answer box at top left green tick.